# multithreaded algo for cycle detection in a directed graph

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I am looking for a concurrent algorithm which would help me in detecting cycles in a directed graph.

I know that the sequential algorithm uses a dfs with colouring, however I think that it will fail in a multi threaded environment. One example of a directed graph to illustrate it:

A->(B, C), B-> (D), D-> (E), C-> (E), E-> (F)

```
                         A
                        / \
                       B   C
                       |   |
                       D   |
                        \ /
                         E
                         |
                         F
```

(I hope the above makes it clear. The edges in the graph are all top to botton)

For the above directed graph, the following execution is possible during concurrent execution.

(the colouring scheme I assumed is white - unvisited, grey - execution of dfs not finished and black - finished execution and visit)

Dfs(B) by thread 1, which eventually colour E as grey and does a dfs(E) (leading to F). Before this is finished, thread 2 executes dfs(C). It realises that E is grey and reports a cycle which is obviously not the case.

I checked that Tarjan's algo could also be used for cycle detection, but again I do not think its execution will be correct in a multi threaded environment.

Could somebody please help me out on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As Ira states let each thread use its own colour.

But, If you have a fixed number of threads use a bit map for each of the colours.
As, long as you processor supports an atomic bit test and set (i.e. BTST on x86) you wont event need locking as each thread will be testing and setting a different bit.

If the bit is set then the item is coloured grey.

PS: If you need more colours then you can use more bits.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. "as Ira states" ? sorry but I cant see any reply from Ira if that is what you mean. Also, I did think about different colours for each thread, but how would you handle a cycle that spans more than 1 thread?

Comment: You have access to all the other threads colours (in the bit array). So you could check to see if it has been visited by someone else. If you skip the ones visited by other threads (copy the colour) then that might work? Do you care about cycles in other threads?

Comment: I need to ensure that the whole graph does not have a cycle. Skipping does not completely help me, as _I think_ it would not detect some of the cycles. Could you please elaborate the algorithm that you are thinking of?

Comment: If another thread has already coloured the item, ignore it (or copy the colour) then you can move onto the next item (i assume there is a processing step for each item). So essentially each thread walks the whole tree as if it is single threaded. You will probably need another colour for start processing, as a semaphore so that two items don't try to process the same item.

Comment: I can't think of a way of safely dividing the graph without walking it at least once.

Comment: So if I have a cycle like this A->B->C->D->A, and A B C and D are processed by different threads, this cycle would not be reported (atleast if I have understood your solution correctly)

Comment: It would. As, you would read all nodes in each thread. BUT, if another thread has coloured it, you copy the colour and skip ahead. That means that Thread 1, processes:B,C,D skips:A. Thread 2, processes: A, skips,B,C,D and it would detect the loop as it would see the coloration for A is already set (as would thread 1 - as it has also walked the whole tree as well). I was thinking there is a better way using a stack, and pushing the exits from the nodes onto a stack (but I am not sure of how to do the end state detection). But, I would need to give that a bit of a think.

Answer (score 1):

For multithreaded cycle detection, it's better to use a variant of the Kahn algorithm (for topological sort) instead of DFS.  This uses the facts that:

1) If a directed graph is acyclic, then it has at least one vertex with no in-edges, and at least one vertex with no out-edges;

2) A vertex with no in-edges or no out-edges cannot participate in a cycle; so

3) If you remove a vertex with no in-edges or no out-edges, you're left with a smaller directed graph with the same cycles as the original.

So, to do a parallel cycle detection, you can:

1) First, use a parallel BFS to build a data structure that keeps track of the in-degree and out-degree of each vertex.

2) Then, in parallel, remove vertices with in-degree or out-degree 0.  Note that removing a vertex will decrement the in-degrees or out-degrees of adjacent nodes.

3) When you're out of vertices to remove, you're left with all the vertices that are involved in cycles.  If there aren't any, then the original graph was acyclic.

Both the parallel BFS (step 1) and parallel vertex removal (step 2) are easily accomplished with parallel work queues.  In step 1, when you see a vertex for the first time, add a task to the queue that processes adjacent vertices.  In step 2, when you decrement a vertex's in-degree or out-degree to 0, add a task to remove it from the graph.

Note that this algorithm works just as well if you remove only nodes with in-degree 0 *or* nodes with out-degree 0, but opportunities for parallelism are somewhat reduced.

Answer (score 0):

You should easily find distributed deadlock detection algorithms, that adress the cycle detection problem.

I understand that distributed isn't exactly multithread, but you should still find hints there.

Edit : added a restricted solution.

Comment: Thanks @Pyra, I did come across a distributed algorithm and will eventually try and implement something similar if I do not get anything better, but I am really hoping I would not have to do that. My main problem is that for distributed algos to work efficiently (I am guessing) there should be minimal edges from one distributed component (of the graph) to the other, which would not be the case for the multi threaded implementation (unless some separation is done before the start of the algorithm)

Comment: Could you clarify your thought ? The paradigm behind most of these distributed algorithm is that every node stores and processes informations, based on the messages that are sent to them. Using a thread, you could easily assume that one step of your thread's walk is a message sent, and that the methods executed by your thread when he visits a node are algorithms executed by that node. Your threaded program would be like a distributed algorithm, with a specific scheduling dictated by the thread's walk order.

Comment: Do you have specific constraints on the datamodel or the way you can walk the graph ?

Comment: For instance, a simple solution which depends on available data (can determine which nodes are roots, can access infos that are on predecessor node) :

Each node holds a variable V whose value is initially equal to the number of predecessor this node has.

Each thread start in one of the roots of the graph, and walks the graph. In each node, the thread lowers the value of V by 1. If V > 0, this node is treated as a leaf, otherwise, the thread may explore its sons.

Once this first walk is done, you do a second walk. If any node vas V>0, then there is a cycle.

Comment: Ok I took two examples to try your solution and understand it. A->B B->C C->B. V for A CB C would be 0 2 1. V(B) would 1 after it is accessed via A and then 0 via C (cycle not detected). However if I say B has been accessed and hence V(B) should remain at 1, then the other example I have proves the algorithm to be wrong. A->C,B->C,C->D. V(C) is 2 and will come down to 1 and if I assume that C has been accessed then V(C) stays at 1 and cycle is reported. Please let me know if I have not understood your algorithm correctly.

Comment: Regarding my first comment, I had come across a parallel algorithm, where the graph is split into various processors. Each processor first tries to find a cycle within itself without caring about the others, and after that one processor tries to find a cycle by looking at the edges that go from one parallel processor to the other. I could try that in multi threading but I will have to try to keep the number of edges between two different threads (or processors in distributed example) to a minimum.

Comment: Regarding your first message, first example ; your algorithm would start at A, and only at A (B and C are not roots). When entering B, V(B) = 2, your algorithm decreases it by 1 so V(B) = 1. Since V(B) >0, your algorithm treats B as a leaf for its walk, and goes back to A, looking for other branches to walk. This thread would not enter C, and any other thread visiting another node of the cycle could not go further into the cycle (because any node of the cycle would be treated as a leaf). The proof that any non-cyclic connected graph (aka a DAG) should be quite simple for you to find.

Comment: Regarding your first message, second example : A and B are roots, so one thread starts in each of these nodes. V(C)=2 as C has 2 predecessors. both threads will visit C ; whichever first thread comes into C decreases V(C) by 1 and V(C) = 1. As V(C)>0, this thread treats C as a leaf, goes back to where it came from, visits other branches and returns. The second thread goes to C, finds V(C)=1 and decreases it, so V(C)=0. As V(C)=0, it is not treated as a leaf, and this thread proceeds to D. V(D)=0 and it is a leaf, so the tread goes back, visits other branches and returns.
V=0 in every node.

Comment: Regarding your second message, this could work, but there are to be some nontrivial constraints on your graph-splitting algorithm. I don't know why you want to check this stuff, but odds are that this first part could harm your computing performance.
The algorithm I submited implicitly splits in the graph in several tree unequally sized. Your algorithm would explicitly split the graph. If you run multiple times on the same graph, pre-processing the spliting so that you have similar-sized trees would be good. If it's a one-shot, implicit spliting would be better.